# Study the continuity of this function

Tags: continuity

I have the function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}; f(x) = \sqrt{x^2+x+1}$. I don't know exactly what should I do since the squre root function is defined only for positive real numbers, and f takes inputs from the whole set of real number. Also if I would study the continuity for $x^2+x+1$ I know that this function is continuous everywhere since it is a polynomial.

Comment: what is the question here?

Comment: Did you ask yourself how can $x^2 + x + 1$ be negative?

Comment: I need to tell if the function is continuous or not (and why )

Comment: it is clear that $$p(x)=x^2+x+1$$ is continuously since $$p(x)$$ is a polynomial

Comment: Yeah but my function is $\sqrt{p(x)}$

Answer (score 2):

$x^2 + x +1 = 0 $ has no solution. As the term with the highest degree is positive, the function is always positive. Thus the square root function gets only positive input for $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$, and so the function $f(x)$ is continuous on the whole $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Thanks that  clears the things a bit. But I should give a $\epsilon - \delta$ argument.